# ASP.Net dynamically add buttons and events to AJAX Accordion Pane

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been searching for a while on this but cant seem to get a decent answer. I am using an Accordion and dynmically adding Panes with grids on. I would also like to add a textbox and a button when each panel is added to the accordion.

```
//add a comments box and a submit button to the container
            Button btnComments = new Button();
            btnComments.ID = CheckName + "btnComment" + i;
            btnComments.CommandName = "SubmitComment";
            TextBox txtComments = new TextBox();
            txtComments.ID = CheckName + "txtComment" + i;
            pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(txtComments);
            pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(btnComments);
```

The textbox and buttons appear in the accordion as expected but the event doesn't fire. I've been reading that the event needs to be added at Page_Load but the buttons dont exist at this point.

I tried adding CommandEvent to the accordion then I could capture the sender but again this isnt firing

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" AutoSize="None" 
            RequireOpenedPane="False" SelectedIndex="-1" FadeTransitions="false"  OnItemCommand="Linked_ItemCommand">
        </asp:Accordion>
        <br />
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRunChecks" runat="server" OnClick="RunChecks" Text="Run Checks" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDebug" runat="server" EnableTheming="False" Text="Run in Debug mode" />
        </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong - any pointers much appreciated. When clicking the button it just causes a postback and refresh losing the dynamically created accordion panes.

Comment: Why are you not adding the buttons through javascript? When adding a button is all you do when clicking on "add" then javascript should be enough and further more it won't execute a postback to the server

Comment: Because I'm not just adding the buttons. I'm calling a webservice in the codebehind and adding the results of that webservice to a GridView. So each pane will have labels, buttons, textbox and a button. The amount of panes is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced a similar issue and after much dismay the only solution is that there is no solution to it.

When you dynamically create controls, regardless of it being for accordion, the controls get created and are sent to the client, where they are rendered as per the client's browser.

**Upon postback, there is no means of re-rendering the controls back on the server as per what  you had added in the page load event. **

This was what I learnt when trying to dynamically add textboxes to a Gridview which can grow in the number of columns: Pre-add a large number of columns with visibility as false and then unhide only the number I require.

If someone out there has a better solution, I'm all game for it!